# In Azure IOThub using Camel component hanging at client.open();

Tags: apache-camel, azure-iot-hub

I have a field gateway that collects data from some devices and I am trying to send that data to IOThub. The gateway is in Camel and so I have to make the sending data to IOThub as a component. I added the following in the Endpoint start() method

```
        connString= "xxxxxxxx";
        protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.AMQPS;
        System.out.println("In start2");
        client = new DeviceClient(connString, protocol);
        System.out.println("In start3");
        client.open();
        System.out.println("In start4");
```

Got the data from the exchange from the Producer and sent it to a method in the endpoint with the following code

```
    Message msg = new Message(payloadBytes);
    Object lockobj = new Object();
    EventCallback callback = new EventCallback();         
    client.sendEventAsync(msg, callback, lockobj);
```

When I run a test route(with a Hello world message), the data goes to the Iothub but it shows the warning below. But when I run the gateway, it hangs at client.open()...Only In start2 and In start3 are printed. In start4 is not.

```
Sep 15, 2016 7:06:10 AM org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.ssl.SslEngineFacadeFactory getClass
WARNING: unable to load org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader
Sep 15, 2016 7:06:10 AM   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.ssl.SslEngineFacadeFactory getClass
WARNING: unable to load org.bouncycastle.openssl.PasswordFinder
Sep 15, 2016 7:06:10 AM org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.ssl.SslEngineFacadeFactory <clinit>
WARNING: unable to load bouncycastle provider
```

I added client.close() in the stop() method of the endpoint. Maybe I am placing the open and close at wrong spots. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure.iot</groupId>
<artifactId>proton-j-azure-iot</artifactId>
<version>0.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
<version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```